# Execute a code when some keyword comes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to execute some code when a specific word found in any controller.
For eg. if I found 'open' in any controller , then 'return' will execute after 'open'

```
def test
    puts "hi"
    open #this is my service code writen in any service class
    puts "after open"
end
```

I want to return to the view immediately when I found open function in any controller.No code written after open will execute.

Comment: this world "open" will be included in html code or where ?

Comment: open will be in controller, basically it is a function written in service

Comment: some maybe you should just create method 'open' ?

Comment: yes , it is writen somewhere, I want to execute a code when this function gets called

Answer (score 0):

I think a [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) would help you:

```
def test
  puts "hi"
  return Proc.new {open}.call #this is my service code written in any service class
  puts "after open"
end
```